# Complex number, power series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Develop $\sinh z$ in powers of $z-\pi i$ to show that $$\lim_{z\to \pi i}\frac{\sinh z}{z-\pi i}=-1$$

I know that $\sinh z=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$.

Edit:

Following the hint I get that $\sinh{(z-\pi i)}=-\sinh{z}$ Then
$$\sinh{(z-\pi i)}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$

But I do not know how to use it to prove that limit, honestly I'm not understand the connection between the power series and the limit

Comment: No, that would be $\sinh(z-\pi i)$, which is something different.

Comment: But you also said, "I suppose that..." and then stated an equality that I was contradicting. No reason to be defensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sinh(a+b)=\sinh a\cosh b+\cosh a\sinh b$. Then use $a=z-\pi i$ and $b=\pi i$.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. The problem wants to use power series.

Comment: @avid19 That's why it is a hint - there is a step after this, using the power series for $\cosh w$ and $\sinh w$.